# Getting all .pdf files from External storage on android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I'm trying to get all pdf's recursively from the External storage. What I'd like to have, is an interface just like pdf reader's, meaning, that it loads the files asynchronously and displays each directory name in a separator. I've got the separator part down, but now I need the loading.

Any tips on doing this? I know that I should just iterate through all files, check if the files is a directory and launch the recursive algorithm again, but how to write this to only show .pdf files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static void searchFolderRecursive1(File folder) {
    if (folder != null) {
        if (folder.listFiles() != null) {
            for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    if(file.getName().contains(".pdf")){
                        Log.v("ooo", "path__="+file.getName());
                    }
                } else {
                    searchFolderRecursive1(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming, that this would also return a file like document.pdf.doc? since it contains .pdf but is not necessarily meant to be a .pdf

Comment: yes, if you want to check the mime type of each file it is also possible but it will be VERY slow. the algorithm is the same only the condition is different, you need to check the mimetype instead of contains(".pdf") ...

Comment: Thanks! This would do it, but in the end, I opted for a Queue based system, since I wanted to process the results of a single folder as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I should just iterate through all files, check if the files is a directory and launch the recursive algorithm again, but how to write this to only show .pdf files?

Look at the file name and see if it ends in `.pdf`, possibly using a `FilenameFilter`, as shown <s>[here](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html)</s>.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ContentResolver** with **Cursor** and **MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE** as "pdf".